# Save post to category with gravity forms (post_data)

Tags: plugins, categories, save-post, plugin-gravity-forms

I'm trying to save my posts, generated with gravity forms, to a specific category. However whatever I try, it's not working. The post must be saved to sepecific category, dependent from a gravity forms field.

What I've tried so far:

```
add_filter("gform_post_data", "change_post_category", 10, 3);      
function change_post_category($post_data, $form, $entry){

    $cat_entry = $entry["6"];
    $catslug = get_category( $cat_entry );

    $post_data["post_category"] = $catslug->slug;
    return $post_data;
}
```

I did also try to change save it with the category id, or by full name. Nothing works. It did however changed from 'no category' to -  (nothing).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The post_category needs to be passed as an array of category IDs (even if you're only adding one category).

Try this:

```
$post_data["post_category"] = array( $catslug->ID );
```